# ssh tunnel only works when logged in to proxying machine

Tags: ssh-tunnel

Ubuntu 18, Firewall not enabled, and I have configured sshd_config to allow forwarding and gateway :

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes
GatewayPorts yes
```

If I create a tunnel listening on all ports:

```
ssh -f -N -L 222:0.0.0.0:22 root@example.com
```

This works fine if I am logged into that machine and connect using localhost:

```
ssh root@localhost -p 222
```

But when I connect to the proxying machine from another machine the connection fails:

```
ssh root@192.168.0.20 -p 222
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.20 port 222: Connection refused
```

What am I doing wrong ??

**EDIT**

```
# lsof -n -i:222
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ssh     4937 root    4u  IPv6 5877871      0t0  TCP [::1]:222 (LISTEN)
ssh     4937 root    5u  IPv4 5877872      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:222 (LISTEN)
```

Even if I kill the original process and create a new process and specify the IP address lsof still shows it only listening on localhost !

```
ssh -f -N -L 222:192.168.0.20:22 root@example.com
```

Comment: What is the output of `lsof -n -i:222` on the host where it is working? Add that to your question.

Comment: Thanks, well it looks like it is only listening on localhost despite using 0.0.0.0 ?!

Comment: Interesting even entering the IP address, and it is still only listening on localhost: ssh -f -N -L 222:192.168.0.20:22 root@example.com

Comment: You should then use `...-L *:222:*:22...`. The port `222` will be opened on the SSH client where you issued the `ssh` command. This port will then be forwarded to the server you are logging into to the port that you specifiy `*:22`.

Comment: Thomas, thanks, yes that works, would you like to add an answer and I will accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `sshd` binds forwarded ports to `localhost` only. One can overwrite this behavior either by using a wildcard or specify an address.

---

For use with wildcard, where `:222::22` is equivalent to `:222::22`

```
user@client$ ssh -L :222::22 server
```

This will open a listener on `client` on `port 222` on all interfaces which will be forwarded to `server:22`.

---

If you want to bind the listener and forwarded address, you can use the IP addresses or hostnames of the corresponding hosts.

```
user@client$ ssh -L client:222:localhost:22 server
```

This will open a listener on `client:22` on the IP address that is resolved to `client` and will be forwarded on `server` to `localhost:22`.

---

Another option would be to use the `GatewayPorts=yes` option in the `ssh` command, which will also open a wildcard listener on `client`.

```
user@client$ ssh -o GatewayPorts=yes -L 222::22 server
```

One could also add this into the `~/.ssh/config` file to make the setting permanent for a specific host.

```
Host server
    GatewayPorts yes
```